# php mysqli login form

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I have been attempting to create a login form. I have been playing around with the code below and still can not get a working login form.

Is there any errors that is stopping my form from working? No matter what i type into the form it takes it to 'login.php' and then just presents a blank screen.

here is my HTML

```
<?php
include('login.php'); // Include Login Script
if ((isset($_SESSION['username']) != '')) 
{
header('Location: home.php');
}
error_reporting(-1);
?>
<form method="post" action="login.php">
<label>Username:</label><br>
<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username" /><br><br>
<label>Password:</label><br>
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" />  <br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Login" /> 
</form>
```

Here is my login.php

```
<?php
session_start();
include("connection.php"); //Establishing connection with our database

$error = ""; //Variable for storing our errors.
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
if(empty($_POST["username"]) || empty($_POST["password"]))
{
$error = "Both fields are required.";
}else
{
// Define $username and $password
$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password'];

// To protect from MySQL injection
$username = stripslashes($username);
$password = stripslashes($password);
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $username);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $password);
$password = md5($password);

//Check username and password from database
$sql="SELECT id FROM staff WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";
$result=mysqli_query($db,$sql);
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

//If username and password exist in our database then create a session.
//Otherwise echo error.

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1)
{
$_SESSION['username'] = $login_user; // Initializing Session
header("location: home.php"); // Redirecting To Other Page
}else
{
$error = "Incorrect username or password.";
}

}
}

?>
```

I have the database setup with the table called 'staff' with "id","username", "password"

Comment: `if ((isset($_SESSION['username']) != ''))` that is invalid syntax and this will never happen `if(isset($_POST["submit"])){...}` and nothing is then used for `$login_user`.

Comment: *To protect from MySQL injection*, you should use prepared statements in that case.

Comment: Add name="submit" in button

Comment: [Your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
 Please learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: You really shouldn't use [MD5 password hashes](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19906/is-md5-considered-insecure) and you really should use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`
Add error checking, such as `or die(mysqli_error())` to your queries. Or you can find the issues in your current error logs.

Comment: Plz update the modified code and use error reporting at top

Comment: What is it?  $login_user????

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100518/discussion-between-devpro-and-jay-blanchard).

Comment: regarding the sql injection, I have 'copied' this from another page and used it on my <code> $sql = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM staff WHERE username='$username' and password='$password");
$sql->bind_param($username, $password);

$sql->execute();

$result = $sql->get_result();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc());</code> Is this how it is done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a name Attribute `name="submit"` to your button:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" />
```

**Why it's needed**

Because you're checking if the name Attribute *submit* is set

```
if (isset ($_POST['submit']))
```

but you didn't set a button name Attribute in the first place.

**Side note**

As others mentioned in the comments you need to protect your code from **SQL Injections.**

---

This is invalid syntax:

```
if ((isset($_SESSION['username']) != ''))
```

You need to check if the session is set **AND** is not equal to nothing/is empty.

```
if (isset($_SESSION['username']) && $_SESSION['username'] != '')
```

You can also shorten that down to just:

```
if (!empty($_SESSION['username']))
```

---

Your initial form should *not* include login.php. Ultimately it would have a `session_start()` function and end up looking more like this:

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['username']) && $_SESSION['username'] != '')
{
    header('Location: home.php');
}
error_reporting(-1);
?>
<form method="post" action="login.php">
    <label>Username:</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username" /><br><br>
    <label>Password:</label><br>
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" />  <br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" /> 
</form>
```

Including login.php here will give you nightmares when it comes to troubleshooting and tracking down errors.

---

You really shouldn't use [MD5 password hashes](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19906/is-md5-considered-insecure) and you really should use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

One more thing, [don't limit passwords](http://jayblanchard.net/security_fail_passwords.html). Limiting passwords, as this [astute cartoon](https://xkcd.com/936/) points out, is a recipe for disaster in this day and age.

Comment: you missed something ;-)

Comment: *Several somethings Ralph.* @Fred-ii-

Comment: @fred-ii plz guide friend... if its major missing than u can downvote :)

Comment: @devpro I've no reason to downvote, plus... I have none left for today lol see my first comment to the OP ;-) the former and not the latter.

Comment: The HTML form is missing a `session_start()` which comes before the syntax error @Fred-ii- points out. *Then* there is the fact that the submit button has no `name`. Past that it is all about SQL injection, MD5 hashing, etc.

Comment: Ahan... @fred-ii u r rock.. I always the input name either using or not well me lost u won the contest...

Comment: @JayBlanchard *This one Sam* `if ((isset($_SESSION['username']) != ''))` ;-)

Comment: *Yeppers Ralph.* Not to mention that login.php is included, but the form is sent to login.php. Lot's of bad mojo here @Fred-ii-

Comment: Yes there r so many issue thats y I mentioned but yes session is another issue... I hope OP will understand the issue... I think my answer is half answer and I dont want to copy yur commemts my friend.. credit goes to u... just thinking to remove my answer @fred-ii

Comment: still not working. I don't understand why. Is there a good guide that I can follow including the prepared statements?

Comment: This will help me in future .. u r such a awesome supporter @fred-ii and I always give u a commemt u r genious..

Comment: @devpro glad I could be of help, *cheers* ;-) let's see what the OP has to say now.

Comment: I provided some links in my comments under your original question about prepared statements @JosephThomasMallinson

Comment: @devpro I'm going to make some improvements to your answer if that is OK.

Comment: I have edit it to what has been said. Still just goes to 'login.php' and shows a white screen

Comment: I have updated it to what is shown in original question.

Comment: Please do not edit your code in the original question @JosephThomasMallinson (I have rolled back) because that prevents new users from coming in and seeing the problem as it relates to the answers given.

Comment: @fred-ii after long discussion with OP I have resolved his issue... issue was undefined variable $login_user .. define in code...  :)

Comment: @jay-blanchard we have resolved this issue chk my last comments

Comment: as were the other two ;-) glad to hear it

Answer (score -2):

taking email and password from a login form.
selecting a table `user` from database.
where email= email & password both are taken by login form

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['login']))
    {
        $email=mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['email']);
        $password=mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password']);

        $login="SELECT * FROM 'user' WHERE 'email' = '$email' AND 'password' = '$password' ";

        $run_login = mysqli_query($db, $login) or die(mysqli_error($db));

        $count = mysqli_num_rows($run_login);
        if($count == 1)
        {
            echo "login success";
        }else
        {
            echo "somthing wrrong";
        }
    }

?>
```